# Should toString() ever return null?

Tags: java, string, tostring

Should the method `toString()` in java ever return null if no conversion could be done or should it return an empty string in that case instead?

Comment: I would argue that `toString` should always return something useful - it's primary case if for debugging. Personally, I'd rely on "formatters" to format an object into a specific `String` representation for display - IMHO. Without more context, every "rule" has an exception

Comment: What would be such an object? Couldn't you just use the default implementation if there is no good string representation?

Comment: Thanks for finding this was a duplicate, the title is a bit obscure to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

null is not String so it is not allowed to return here. Check Java Docs:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

it should return a  meaningful string representation of the object. I wrote an example of how to use it and why it is useful:

```
public class Car {
    private String make;
    private int year;
    public Car(String make, int year) {
        this.make = make;
        this.year = year;
    }    

    @Overrride
    public String toString() {
        return "Car Make:" + make + "; Built Year: " + year;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Car myCar = new Car("Nissan", 1999);
Car yourCar = new Car("BMW", 2018);
System.out.println(myCar);  // call toString() implicitly
System.out.println(yourCar);
```

It will print 2 lines and you can easily read the text and know which is your car!

```
Car Make:Nissan; Built Year: 1999
Car Make:BMW; Built Year: 2018
```

Answer (score 3):

`toString()` returning null would be very bad API design. Clearly, if you are able to call `toString()` on it, the object is clearly not null. Otherwise, there would be a `NullPointerException`.

It really depends on the Object and what the use case is. Empty string is ok if you are using `toString()` to do real logic - e.g, if you use `toString()` as the key to a key-value store. If it is simply used for debugging/logging. Just print out all the fields. e.g, something like what [MoreObjects.toStringHelper()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.ToStringHelper.html) does.

Comment: IMHO using the return of `toString()` for any sort of  "real logic", and especially using it as a _[unique] key_ would be, to put it rather politely, **ill-advised**.

Comment: @KevinAnderson True. I don't condone it. But I have seen legacy systems rely on it, exactly for the use case I mentioned. In that case, it's ok if empty string is the expected representation. But `toString()` returning null would just make me quit.

Comment: Legacy systems... don't even get me started!

Answer (score 3):

The Java API documentation, every recent version I have checked, says:

> **Returns**:
>       a string representation of the object.

In other words **null** is not a defined return value.  If you don't override the **toString()** method then you will always get a string that at least gives you the Object's ID.

Although this does not rule out that possibility of an overriding method  returning **null**, any programmer who does this should expect a lot of NPEs from tools and frameworks that might be operating on that code.

My opinion:  don't do it.

My question: what kind of object could not be represented by a string?